# Set header and footer in Vsmoraes PDF laravel5?

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I am using [Vsmoraes PDF](https://github.com/vsmoraes/pdf-laravel5) for generating pdf in laravel5. I am converting HTML in to PDF.

```
    $router->get('/pdf/view', function() {
    $html = view('pdfs.example')->render();

    return PDF::load($html)->show();
});
```

I want to set page number,page header and footer. How it is possible using this pacakge?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the package but the classes are quite simple. Neither footer nor header are mencioned. But, it's just a Laravel module for DOMPDF and [according to their wiki](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ), you can do it.